# Can MFCC consist any zero values?

Tags: audio, mfcc

After extracting audio features using some library, I just realized that sometimes it (MFCC) might or might not have zero values. At what time/event does MFCC could have zero values? Because it's (some zero values on MFCC) not appeared on every audio files.

And also, can we use some value (0 or anything) as don't care value on MFCC?